# d3 circles on a leaflet map

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am using the following code to generate a map with circles;

http://jsbin.com/OTaKEDor/2/edit

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.9/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' id='lt_ws' src='http://localhost:52656/socket.io/lighttable/ws.js'></script>

<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;" class="leaflet-container leaflet-fade-anim" tabindex="0">
</div>

<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.82, 5.861], 11); 
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: ''
  }).addTo(map);

  var data = [ [5.861797,51.822823],[5.861843,51.822815],[5.5102863,51.78242],[5.8564305,51.821033],[5.859349,51.822502] ];

  var plotData = data.map( function( coord ){ 
    return map.latLngToLayerPoint( [ coord[1], coord[0] ] );
  });

  var svg = d3.select( map.getPanes().overlayPane ).append("svg"), 
      g   = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

  g.selectAll("circle").data( plotData ).enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; } )
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; } )
    .attr("r", 25)
    .style("fill", "black");

</script>
```

I map the coordinates to leaflet such that it is placed on the right spot. The problem is that the circles are placed on the svg on the leaflet map, google devtools confirms this, but they dont get the right attributes, they remain invisible.

See screenshot;

[image]

Is there something that I have forgotten to do?

Comment: Are you setting size and position of the SVG appropriately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this worked, this is better code as well, now the data binds to the svg elements which allows for much more interactivity;

```
function drawCircles(){
  var data = [
    { "coords" : [ 37.8 , - 96.8 ], "time" : 1 },
    { "coords" : [ 33.6 , - 96.6 ], "time" : 5 },
    { "coords" : [ 40.5 , - 96.3 ], "time" : 4 },
    { "coords" : [ 37.4 , - 66.6 ], "time" : 3 },
    { "coords" : [ 37.8 , - 97.6 ], "time" : 2 }
  ].map( function(d){ var newPoint = map.latLngToLayerPoint( d.coords ); d.coords = { 'x' : newPoint.x, 'y' : newPoint.y }; return d; } )

  g.selectAll("circle").data( data ).enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d){ console.log(d); return d.coords.x } )
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.coords.y } )
    .attr("r", 5 )
    .style("fill", "teal")
}
```