# d3 overlay on google maps in a meteor application

Tags: google-maps, d3.js, meteor

I am having trouble understanding d3 overlays with a google map in conjunction with meteor.
My html:

```
<template name = "googlemap">
  <div class = "hero-unit">
    {{#constant}}
      <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%">
        <svg>
        </svg>
      </div>
    {{/constant}}
  </div>
</template>
```

My js:

```
  Template.googlemap.rendered = function () {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.041132,-106.522532),
      zoom: 19,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
   //Create Google Map
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
   //Create an overlay for the map
   var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
   //Data = center of map
   var data = [{name:"pt1",lng:35.041132,lat:-106.522532}];

   overlay.onAdd = function() {
     var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div").attr("height", "100%").attr("width", "100%");

     overlay.draw = function() {
       var projection = this.getProjection();
       var point = layer.selectAll("svg").data(data).enter().append("svg:svg");
       // Add marker on points
       point.append("svg:circle").attr("r", 4.5);
     };
  };

   overlay.setMap(map);  
 };
```

The creation of the google map works and it is visible. However I cannot draw the circle overlay.The code that I don't understand how to incorporate is the `overlay.onAdd` and everything after that.I also do have the d3 package in my meteor project. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine the problem is that it doesn't know where to place the SVG. I would suggest trying the following:
CSS (for large SVG images to avoid clipping):

```
.SvgOverlay svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: -4000px;
    left: -4000px;
    width: 8000px;
    height: 8000px;
}
```

JS:

```
//If you are overlaying a large image on the map, you probably want to offset by this amount in the css so that you don't get clipping.
svgOverlayOffset = 4000;
var svg = layer.append("svg");
overlay.draw = function() {
    //Draw is called every time a pan/zoom happens so if you add something here (such as the svg layer), you will end up with a lot of them. 
    //Defines the selection. identifyFunction is something that will give each element of your data a unique ID.
    //This allows the selection to work, otherwise you end up with the same data not matching an element and the enter selection will always happen.
    var point = svg.selectAll("circle")
                 .data(data, identifyFunction);
    //Creates the circle if we haven't encountered this data before.
    point.enter().append("svg:circle");
    //Updates the circle; Since this is after the enter, it will work on the first call too.
    point.each(transform);
    //Removes the circle if the data related to it has disappeared.
    point.exit().remove();
}
function transform(d) {
     //other information can be pulled before modifying, e.g., type = d["type"] or d["radius"]
     d = latLngToPixel(d["latitude"], d["longitude"])
     return d3.select(this)
         .attr("r", 4.5)
         .attr("cx", d[0])
         .attr("cy", d[1])
};
function latLngToPixel(lat, lng) {
     var googleCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
     var pixelCoordinates = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(googleCoordinates);
     return [pixelCoordinates.x + 4000, pixelCoordinates.y + 4000];
}
```

You could try [d3 circles on a leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909948/d3-circles-on-a-leaflet-map) for a good example.